# Javascript DOM gradually change opacity

Tags: javascript, html, dom, setinterval

```
function fade()
{

    var i = 0;
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
    h1.style.opacity = 0;
    var k = window.setInterval(function()
    {
        if(i >= 10)
            clearInterval(k);
        else
        {
            h1.style.opacity += i/10;
            i++;
        }
    }     

            , 10);


};
```

This is my function, it's supposed to gradually increase the opacity of an h1 tag, making a fade-in animation effect , but it stops after the first loop(when opacity is 0.1).

The function is called onload inside my body tag if that helps a bit.

Comment: Check the braces on your conditional. Pretty sure the missing ones are going to cause an error. Have a look at the browser console to see.

Comment: checked, the braces are alright and the function does work, but it stops after 0.1, even though it should stop at 1.0

Comment: Incidentally, you might consider using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: I would if the assignment didn't specifically ask for a javascript animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to *add* the result of the calculation to the opacity, you want to set it:

```
h1.style.opacity = i / 10;
```

You might also want to slow down the interval a bit. YMMV though.

Here's the full code:

```js
function fade() {
  var i = 0;
  var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  h1.style.opacity = 0;
  var k = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (i >= 10) {
      clearInterval(k);
    } else {
      h1.style.opacity = i / 10;
      i++;
    }
  }, 100);
};
fade()
```

```html
<h1>
  My heading
</h1>
```